# I can't get a video to play on my nginx server through kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, nginx

again. I tried all of your suggestions and couldn't figure it out. For the newcomers to this post, I am trying to get a local video on a nginx server hosted with Kubernetes. I have tried more, and now my files look as so

configMap:

```
    apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:

  name: index-html-configmap
  namespace: default

data:
  index.html:

    <video width="1920" height="1080" autoplay loop muted>
    <source src="/usr/share/nginx/html/video/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />

    Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>`
```

Deployment file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1

kind: Deployment

metadata:

  name: nginx-deployment
  namespace: default

spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:

      - name: nginx

        image: nginx:latest

        ports:

        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
            - name: nginx-index-file
              mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
            - name: movie
              mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html/video/movie.mp4
      volumes:
      - name: nginx-index-file

        configMap:
          name: index-html-configmap
      - name: movie
        configMap:
          name: index-html-configmap
```

Please help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi thatonecoder welcome to SO. This is not a programming question, and thus is [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). That said, you seem to be running the vanilla nginx image, which for sure does not have your movie.mp4 in the image, and you have only volume mounted one ConfigMap, which I also gravely doubt contains your video, so where are you expecting nginx to find that file?

Answer (score 0):

First look from it, I can see that config-map is not mounted into the volume. You need to refer the configmap in the volume.

```
  volumes:
  - name: nginx-index-file
    configMap:
      name: "index-html-configmap"
```

Update this entry in your configmap, and redeploy.

Also, If haven't done this way, I would suggest you adding the to html files, and then creating the ConfigMap by referring to it.
`kubectl create index-html-configmap  --from-file=index.html`

You can refer the official documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/).